# Permission denied to NFS directory 0770

Tags: permissions, nfs

In my workplace we have a shared NFS storage mounted on a computing cluster. The working group's parent directory and each user's directory in it have `0770` permissions so we should be able to have full access to each other's directories. But we get `permission denied`.

We are member of a group representing the working group:

```
$ id
uid=4171(deeenes) gid=2073(wg) groups=2073(wg), ...
$ id colleague
uid=4386(colleague) gid=2073(wg) groups=2073(wg), ...
```

The NFS storage is mounted on `/net/data`:

```
$ mount | grep net/data
xxx:/yyy on /net/data type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=***,local_lock=none,addr=***)
```

We are able to list our working group's directory in it:

```
ls -la /net/data/wg
total 7325
drwxrwx--- 22 wg_admin    wg             652 Sep 17 15:06 .
drwxrwxr-x 25 root        4294967294     606 Aug  6 09:43 ..
drwxrwx---  2 deeenes     wg             836 Aug 28 16:11 deeenes
drwxrwx---  5 4294967294  wg             248 Sep 18 09:41 colleague
...
```

`4294967294` appears to be an unknown user ID.

I can access my own directory `/net/data/deeenes` but for the colleague's directory I get `permission denied`:

```
$ ls /net/data/wg/colleague
ls: cannot open directory /net/data/wg/colleague: Permission denied
```

I asked the system administrators in charge but they have no idea.
I especially don't understand because the parent directory is in the same NFS mount with the same GID and permissions regarding the group and I can access it. The group and user names and IDs on these directories match the ones on the client system:

```
$ stat -c "%G(%g) %U(%u)" ~
wg(2073) deeenes(4171)
$ stat -c "%G(%g) %U(%u)" /net/data/wg/deeenes
wg(2073) deeenes(4171)
$ stat -c "%G(%g) %U(%u)" /net/data/wg/colleague
wg(2073) UNKNOWN(4294967294)
$ stat -c "%G(%g) %U(%u)" /net/data/wg/colleague2
wg(2073) colleague2(4243)
```

Looks like `colleague` does not exist on the server system but the group does, and I also can not access the directory of `colleague2` whos UID matches between the systems.

Comment: Did you try to give execute permissions for everyone in order to operate a directory?You can do:

chmod +x /net/data/colleague

Comment: I am not allowed to `chmod` but I know if the permission is `777` then I can access (we have one such directory), so what you suggest would work.

Comment: What is the setting in the exports file of the server?

Comment: @Johan, yes I know. Seems like I am member of the group, but then the 3rd bits should not have an effect and I should have access. And if I am not a member, I should not be able to list the parent directory. This is a contradiction.

Comment: @muru, I don't know I am not admin on any of these computers

Comment: @deeenes however. you can ask the admins, and you have stated they do respond to your queries.